# How should I share Activity related code between multiple activities?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have several bits of functionality that I need in multiple activities in my app. They need to be able to access Activity methods, and in some cases override methods (e.g. I have some shared functionality to choose pictures from the Gallery that needs to handle `onRequestPermissionsResult`).

Any one of these is simple - I can create a XXXBase class, and then my Activity can derive from it. If I need more than one of these in my Activity though, I am limited by inheritance mechanics.

I could put all of this extra functionality in one common Base class that is used repeatedly, but that class could end up getting quite big and unwieldy.

Is there an alternative approach that I'm missing? I'm using Kotlin, if that opens up any extra possibilities.

Comment: It's quite common to have an utility class ( usually singleton) or you just go for a static method.

Comment: Usually, I organise my reusable methods in a utils class and let the activities call them. If you feel like the class is getting big, try to split it down into smaller classes based on functionality or theme.

Comment: In Kotlin You can use [Delegation Pattern](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html) or [Interface with default implementation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html) depending on your use case.

Comment: @pawel Interface with default implementation does actually seem to be a good language level approach. The headless fragment approach below probably works a little better in this particular case as the event passing when using multiple helpers will work automatically rather than having to be implemented in the activity, but I learned from your answers so thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you need to override certain framework methods, I think this actually would be a great case for using a headless `Fragment`. Using a `Fragment`, you can start `Activity`s, request permissions, handle the results, etc. Using this pattern, this `Fragment` can be attached to any `Activity` (or even another `Fragment` as a child). You of course could break down further classes that this headless `Fragment` relies on internally, but I would definitely suggest looking into a `Fragment`-based approach.

For example:

```
private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION: Int = 1

class MyUtilityFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // do permission request
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ): {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        // handle your permission result here
    }
}
```

Then in your `Activity`, you can just attach it in `onCreate()` and let it do its thing:

```
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(MyUtilityFragment(), "utility_fragment")
                .commitNow()
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to provide results back to the host, you can just designate an interface in your `Fragment`, and have the hosting parent `Fragment` or `Activity` implement that interface, and then retrieve it from the headless `Fragment` when needed:

```
private fun getCallback() : MyCallbackInterface {
    parentFragment?.takeIf { it is MyCallbackInterface }?.let { return it as MyCallbackInterface }
    return requireActivity() as MyCallbackInterface
}
```